# Extract certain substring using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I have a word which has a section say `1.2.2` and a `some text` followed by `some other texts`. I want to get the section. I have created a regex to match the section and some text.

Below is my code:

```
var word = "1.2.3 area consent testing, sklfjsdlkf jdifgjds visjeflk area consent testing lsdajfgo idsjgosa jfikdjfl343 fjdsl45jl sfgjsoiaetj l area consent testing";
var lowerWord = "area consent testing".ToLower();
var textLower = @word.ToLower().ToString();
Dictionary<int, string> matchRegex = new Dictionary<int, string>();
matchRegex.Add(1, @"(^\d.+(?:\.\d+)*[ \t](" + lowerWord + "))"); 


foreach (var check in matchRegex)
{
    string AllowedChars = check.Value;
    Regex regex = new Regex(AllowedChars);
    var match = regex.Match(textLower);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var sectionVal = match.Value;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, I just want the value `1.2.3 area consent testing` in my `sectionVal` variable, but it is giving me the whole line as it is.
i.e.

```
sectionVal = "1.2.3 area consent testing, sklfjsdlkf jdifgjds visjeflk area consent testing lsdajfgo idsjgosa jfikdjfl343 fjdsl45jl sfgjsoiaetj l area consent testing";
```

Comment: Shouldn't `\d.+` be `\d+\.`? - *escape* the first `.`

Comment: `$@"^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*\s{Regex.Escape(lowerCase)}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start of your regex contains an unescaped `.` which will match any character and a `+` after. Try this:

```
@"^(\d+(\.\d+)*[ \t](" + lowerWord + "))"
```

Comment: @Titianm, you are the saviour!

Comment: `[ \t]` can, probably, be turned into `\s`; `+ Regex.Escape(lowerCase) + `  instead of `+ lowerCase +` to be on the *safe side*